# Development and testing a Windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services

If I'm developing a service, do I need to unregister and register the service every time I compile the exe? Or just stopping, changing the file and starting is perfectly enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you have registered the program as a service, that method (stop/replace/start) will work in development, testing, and production. No need to register it again.